# Flutter. Axis values in a realtime fl_chart

Tags: flutter, dart, fl-chart

**Flutter with fl_chart: How can I dynamically set up the values shown in X and Y axis for a chart which is refreshed in realtime?**
(I have tried  to use AxisTitles and bottomTitleWidgets. No luck)

Details:
My flutter application shows a fl_chart which is   refreshed in real time . The 'Y' axe corresponds to brightness  magnitudes (double, from 0 to 30) and X axe corresponds to timestamp of the event (int, milliseconds).
I'd like to find a way to dynamically set up the values shown in both axis:

- For the Y axe, the scale should be  [lower value -1, higher value +1]
- For the X Axe, more tricky, I'd like timestamps in format  HH:mm:ss. BUT!, since the chart can be shown for a big amount of time (say hours), it should adapt the timescale of the events to show always a fixed number of values in the axe.

The  chart is refreshed here:

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
    setState(() {
      currentDateTime = DateTime.now();
      xValue = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch as double;
      //widget.SQMTELValue is asynchronously updated elsewhere
      SQMTelPoints.add(FlSpot(xValue, widget.SQMTELValue));
    });
  });
```

I have attempted to use AxisTitles and bottomTitleWidgets objects to customize the values in the x axe , with no luck

Using In the chart definition returned from build():

```
titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                      show: true,

                      //!!!!!!!Attempt to use a custom AxisTitles!!!!!!
                      bottomTitles: AxisTitles(sideTitles: bottomTitle),

                      topTitles: const AxisTitles(
                      sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false))),
                ),
```

The definition of bottomTitle:

```
SideTitles get bottomTitle => const SideTitles(
  showTitles: true,
  reservedSize: 32,
  interval: 1,
  getTitlesWidget: bottomTitleWidgets,
  
);
```

and the definition of bottomTitleWidgets where I *think* the solution should be implemented

```
  Widget bottomTitleWidgets(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
  const style = TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: 16,
  );

  ///////////////////////////////////
  ///Here should be implemented the solution, i Think
 ///////////////////

  return SideTitleWidget(
    axisSide: meta.axisSide,
    space: 10,
    child: text,
    fitInside: SideTitleFitInsideData.disable(),
    
  );
}
```

Currently, shows a nasty bunch o values on X and a fixed scal of avlues on Y (forced by me)

[image]